# Lowest Michaelis constant Km

Tags: kinetics, chemical-biology, enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

I want to find a lower limit of the Michaelis constant for some evaluations of Michaelis-Menten enzyme kinetics.
What is the lowest $K_m$ you ever encountered? Is there a theoretical limit?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics#Applications

Comment: The link does provide some examples, but no lower limit for k_m.

Comment: It is generally believed that evolution places a theoretical limit on kcat/Km, but not necessarily on Km. I know of one reported Km in the nanomolar rnage (3.2 nM to be precise): https://aem.asm.org/content/85/13/e00438-19. There are probably others that are lower.

Comment: Since the function under consideration is catalytic (accelerating the reaction rate), you might consider the natural rate of the reaction (in absence of enzyme) as setting a limit on kcat. From the diffusion limited on rate (as explained in an answer) and setting the off-rate kr to zero you can  estimate a lower meaningful (theoretical) bound on Km.

Comment: The other way to set an upper limit on kcat is by the lifetime of the enzyme. Most cellular proteins are degraded within hours or days. So you could set a conservative lifetime as 100 days and say that at least one turnover must happen (on average) within that time, so minimum kcat is 3 per year ~ $1\times 10^{-8}$ s$^{-1}$. Dividing by kf = 10^9 M-1s-1 gives a limit on Km of $10^{-17}$ M give or take a few orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this generic reaction representing the Michaelis-Menten enzyme kinetic:

[image]

You can derive the Michaelis-Manten constant $K_m$:

 (for derivation see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics)

[image]

The quasi-steady state hypothesis was used, therefore the rate of formation and breakdown of $ES$ are the same; this is a good approximation if the enzyme concentration is much less than the substrate concentration $[S]$ or $K_m$ or both. That means that $K_m$ can be extremely small (almost zero) and the Michaelis-Menten equation still be valid proven that the enzyme concentration is much less than  $[S]$.

$K_m$ is very small if:

$k_r$ and $k_{cat}$ are both very small compared to $k_f$, thus if the complex $ES$ is formed very quickly compared to its breakdown.

In this case the reaction proceeds at its maximum velocity $V_{max}=k_{cat}*E_0$, with $E_0=[ES]+[E]$:

[image]

About the theoretical limit on how small $K_m$ can be there are two considerations:

 First, $k_f$ cannot be cannot be faster than the diffusion-controlled encounter of an enzyme and its substrate. This means that $k_f$ cannot be higher than $10^9 s^{-1} M^{-1}$  (ref.https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22430/#:~:text=This%20rate%20cannot%20be%20faster,s%2D1%20M%2D1.)

Second, $k_{cat}$ cannot be too small or the product $P$ formed is produced at a rate not suitable for the cell survival.

Generally, I haven't encountered $K_m$ smaller than $10^{-6}M$ in biological enzymes (e.g Triosephosphate isomerase, TPI) but possibly there are. In TPI, $ k_f$ ∼ $10^9 s^{-1} M^{-1}$, therefore  $k_r$  ∼ $k_{cat}$  ∼ $10^{3}s^{-1}$ that is still quite high. It would be very interesting to know if there are enzymes with an even lower $K_m$. Very intresting question.